# Problems with building a project in CodeNameOne

Tags: java, android, codenameone

Suddenly I can't build any projects in Netbeans with CN1.

The message on the console:
Created dir: C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\Tempus\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\Tempus\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\Tempus\build
C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\Tempus\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1387: Unable to delete file C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\Tempus\dist\README.TXT
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

The error is: `Unable to delete file C:\Users\ruben\Documents\ProyectosCodenameOne\Tempus\dist\README.TXT`

Try deleting it. Make sure permissions for the directory are set so the build script can delete/create files there.